# SQlBulkCopy The given value of type DateTime from the data source cannot be converted to type int of the specified target column

Tags: c#, sql, performance, parsing

I am receiving the above error code when attempting to do a SqlBulkInsert of the following "Cities" DataTable:

```
DataTable cityTable = new DataTable(City.TABLE_NAME);
cityTable.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
cityTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
cityTable.Columns.Add("ascii_name", typeof(string));
cityTable.Columns.Add("alternate_names", typeof(string));
cityTable.Columns.Add("latitude", typeof(double));
cityTable.Columns.Add("longitude", typeof(double));
cityTable.Columns.Add("feature_class", typeof(char));
cityTable.Columns.Add("feature_code", typeof(string));
cityTable.Columns.Add("country_code", typeof(string));
cityTable.Columns.Add("country_code2", typeof(string));
cityTable.Columns.Add("population", typeof(long));
cityTable.Columns.Add("elevation", typeof(int));
cityTable.Columns.Add("modification_date", typeof(DateTime));
cityTable.Columns.Add("admin1code", typeof(string));
cityTable.Columns.Add("admin2code", typeof(string));
cityTable.Columns.Add("admin3code", typeof(string));
cityTable.Columns.Add("admin4code", typeof(string));
cityTable.Columns.Add("gtopo30", typeof(int));
cityTable.Columns.Add("timezone_name", typeof(string));
cityTable.Columns.Add("version", typeof(Binary));
```

The following is the code that adds each entity to the DataTable:

```
object id = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.Id);
object name = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.Name);
object asciiName = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.AsciiName);
object alternateNames = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.AlternateNames);
object latitude = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.Latitude);
object longitude = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.Longitude);
object featureClass = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.FeatureClass);
object featureCode = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.FeatureCode);
object countryCode = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.CountryCode);
object countryCode2 = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.CountryCode2);
object population = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.Population);
object elevation = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.Elevation);
object modificationDate = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.ModificationDate);
object admin1Code = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.Admin1Code);
object admin2Code = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.Admin2Code);
object admin3Code = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.Admin3Code);
object admin4Code = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.Admin4Code);
object gtopo30 = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.Gtopo30);
object timeZoneName = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.TimeZoneName);
object version = EvaluateNullity(parsedCity.Version);

cityRow["id"] = id;
cityRow["name"] = name;
cityRow["ascii_name"] = asciiName;
cityRow["alternate_names"] = alternateNames;
cityRow["latitude"] = latitude;
cityRow["longitude"] = longitude;
cityRow["feature_class"] = featureClass;
cityRow["feature_code"] = featureCode;
cityRow["country_code"] = countryCode;
cityRow["country_code2"] = countryCode2;
cityRow["population"] = population;
cityRow["elevation"] = elevation;
cityRow["modification_date"] = modificationDate;
cityRow["admin1code"] = admin1Code;
cityRow["admin2code"] = admin2Code;
cityRow["admin3code"] = admin3Code;
cityRow["admin4code"] = admin4Code;
cityRow["gtopo30"] = gtopo30;
cityRow["timezone_name"] = timeZoneName;
cityRow["version"] = version;
```

And the code for EvaluateNullity:

```
    public object EvaluateNullity(object entity)
    {
        return entity ?? DBNull.Value;
    }
```

My understanding from this error message is that A DateTime value is being placed in one of the above int columns.
However, a quick conditional debug later, and checks in the Immediate Window  reveal that none of the int columns ever have DateTime types being placed in them.
http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg42/scaled.php?server=42&filename=mod1rm.jpg&res=landing
http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg37/scaled.php?server=37&filename=modyf.jpg&res=landing

I am really stumped.

Comment: Double check that the order of the columns defined in cityTable matches the order of columns within the database table itself.

Comment: Thank you David Andres!!!!!!!!
Spent all day yesterday trying to debug this issue, I had NO idea that the order you defined the columns actually affected this!
I wanted to mark your solution as answer but it seems you wrote it as a comment instead of an answer...

Comment: Isnt that a bit silly? The framework should take care of that.

Comment: @Francisco: Glad to see that this worked for you.  This one caught me by surprise when I first encountered it, but I doubt it ever will again!  =)  No worries about the points for the answer, as this is an easy quirk to overlook.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From David Andres:

> Double check that the order of the columns defined in cityTable
>   matches the order of columns within the database table itself.

Comment: I have explained this a bit more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892702/the-given-value-of-type-string-from-the-data-source-cannot-be-converted-to-type/20542022#20542022). In fact its not only the order, but the index of the destination columns should be mapped to the source table's columns. You can do it with SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping.

Comment: @David Andres I also have the same issue with DateTime datatype, but suprisingly when I upload excel file, first time it stops at this error, but next time when I upload the same excel file, it gets upload successfully without any error. I have no idea why this is happening. Please suggest

Answer (score 13):

One non-obvious cause of this error is that you must have a property representing identity columns, even though you can leave them unset.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a mismatch between the entity **framework model class** and the actual table (forgot to scaffold the table model from db):

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Databases
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class FooTable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // --> Missing the LastUpdated Column.
    }
}
```

The Table:
[image]