# The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type bigint of the specified target column

Tags: c#, sql

That's my code :

```
protected void SendToServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable Values = Session["valuesdt"] as DataTable;

    if (Values.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        //Fix up default values
        for (int i = 0; i < Values.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Values.Rows[i]["Mobile1"] = Values.Rows[i]["Mobile1"].ToString() == "" ? 0 : double.Parse(Values.Rows[i]["Mobile1"].ToString());
            Values.Rows[i]["Mobile2"] = Values.Rows[i]["Mobile2"].ToString() == "" ? 0 : double.Parse(Values.Rows[i]["Mobile2"].ToString());
            Values.Rows[i]["Tel"] = Values.Rows[i]["Tel"].ToString() == "" ? 0 : double.Parse(Values.Rows[i]["Tel"].ToString());
            Values.Rows[i]["Category"] = Values.Rows[i]["Category"].ToString();
        }

        DataTable dv = Values.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Mobile1", "Mobile2", "Tel", "Category");
        BulckCopyDataTable(dv, "client", 1000);
    }
}

public void BulckCopyDataTable(DataTable dt,string DestinationTable,int batchSize)
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    {
        copy.BatchSize = batchSize;
        copy.DestinationTableName = DestinationTable;
        copy.WriteToServer(dt);
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this error is been throws in the database :

```
Mobile1 bigint, Mobile2 bigint, Tel bigint, Category nvarchar(MAX)
```

Comment: Check datatypes for `Mobile1`, `Mobile2`, `Tel` in `Values` DataTable

Comment: What @AndreyGordeev said. Also, I don't think it's a good idea to store phone numbers in a numeric format. Some (most?) numbers start with a zero, you'll lose that if you convert it to a number. and most people write it down in groups (`+12 (3456) 789 654 432`) and they expect to get it back in exactly that format.

Comment: thank u very much i've changed the dataType of my columns to nvarchar in my sqql table and it work properly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an answer in [this bytes.com thread](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/808539-sqlbulkcopy-writetoserver-blowing-up-tables-identitycolumns).

All you have to do is map the columns of the source to the destination table with the use of SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping.

```
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(0, 1));
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(1, 2));
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(2, 3));
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(3, 6)); //look here, index is different
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(4, 8)); //and again
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(5, 9));
```

I also found the same solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919593/sqlbulkcopy-the-given-value-of-type-datetime-from-the-data-source-cannot-be-conv) before finding the above, but in my case I had some fields missing in the source. The fields were in the correct order although it referred to the actual INDEX/ORDER of the fields. If I didn't have the missing fields it would have worked.

Comment: I also have the same issue with DateTime datatype, but suprisingly when I upload excel file, first time it stops at this error, but next time when I upload the same excel file, it gets upload successfully without any error. I have no idea why this is happening. Please suggest.